# asp.net web api 2 LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-web-api

I want to invoke method durning mapping my domain class to DTO class but after many tries with LINQ to Entities or LINQ to objects i have failed and i'm getting weird different errors. Actulal error is just a "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ResizeToLogoImage(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.".

Mapping method:

```
public async Task<SingleCategory> SingleCategoryMapping(EventerApiContext context, int id)
    {
        var category = await context.Category.Select(c => new SingleCategory
        {
            CategoryId = c.CategoryId,
            CategoryName = c.CategoryName,
            CityId = c.CityId,
            Events = context.Event.ToList().Where(e=>e.CategoryId == id).Select(e=> new EventForSingleCategory
            {
                EventId = e.EventId,
                EventName = e.EventName,
                EventLogo = ImageProcessor.ResizeToLogoImage(e.EventDetail.EventImage.EventImageBase64)
            }).ToList()
        }).SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CategoryId == id);

        return category;
    }
```

Method to be invoked.

```
public static string ResizeToLogoImage(string base64String)
    {
        if (base64String == null)
        {
            return "NULL";
        }
        var imageToResize = Base64ToImage(base64String);
        var resizedImage = ScaleImage(imageToResize, 50, 50);
        return ImageToBase64(resizedImage, imageToResize.RawFormat);
    }
```

I know error is appearing during EventLogo property mapping but i have no more idea what to do.

Comment: Well, this expression can't be translated in an sql query, that's it. So, you've got to go out of the `IQueryable` world before applying this method. Question : don't you have a navigation property between Event and Category ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the data first, before you do the Select statement. I suspect that it is trying to execute ResizeToLogoImage on the database :)